# Log on eclipse for displaying the map in android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I get following log when i tried to display the map.

Log is:-

```
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 33/zygote: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 32 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 85/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   0% 37/qemud: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):  +0% 337/com.android.deskclock: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):  +0% 363/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89): 99% TOTAL: 69% user + 29% kernel + 0.4% softirq
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89): CPU usage from 6214ms to 7514ms later:
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   36% 89/system_server: 27% user + 9% kernel / faults: 246 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     15% 98/er.ServerThread: 12% user + 2.7% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     7.2% 99/ActivityManager: 4.5% user + 2.7% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     2.7% 241/Binder Thread #: 2.7% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     1.8% 95/Binder Thread #: 0.9% user + 0.9% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     1.8% 96/Binder Thread #: 0.9% user + 0.9% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     1.8% 123/PowerManagerSer: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.9% 94/Compiler: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.9% 240/Binder Thread #: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.9% 256/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.9% 257/Binder Thread #: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   10% 174/app_process: 9% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 51 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   5% 208/com.android.phone: 3.9% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 221 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     3.9% 208/m.android.phone: 3.3% user + 0.5% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 210/HeapWorker: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 218/GC: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 235/Binder Thread #: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):    +0% 355/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):    +0% 356/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   3.8% 180/com.android.systemui: 3.2% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 119 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     3.8% 180/ndroid.systemui: 3.2% user + 0.5% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 192/Binder Thread #: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 193/Binder Thread #: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   4.1% 276/com.google.process.gapps: 2.9% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 54 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     2.9% 276/e.process.gapps: 2.9% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 282/Binder Thread #: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):    +0% 358/AsyncTask #1: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):    +0% 360/Thread-21: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   3.8% 299/com.android.launcher: 2.2% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 186 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     2.7% 333/launcher-loader: 1.1% user + 1.6% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     1.1% 299/ndroid.launcher: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   4.5% 62/bootanimation: 3.6% user + 0.9% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     5.4% 65/BootAnimation: 4.5% user + 0.9% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   3.3% 32/surfaceflinger: 2.5% user + 0.8% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     3.3% 59/SurfaceFlinger: 1.6% user + 1.6% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.8% 32/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.8% 61/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   3.5% 42/adbd: 2.6% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 2 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     4.4% 78/adbd: 4.4% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     2.6% 42/adbd: 2.6% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.8% 77/adbd: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   1.1% 337/com.android.deskclock: 0% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 11 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 337/droid.deskclock: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 350/AsyncHandler: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.7% 1//init: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.9% 85/logcat: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.5% 284/android.process.acore: 0.5% user + 0% kernel / faults: 31 minor
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 286/GC: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.5% 316/ApplicationsPro: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-17 13:01:49.846: E/ActivityManager(89): 100% TOTAL: 77% user + 22% kernel + 0.8% softirq
09-17 13:01:53.555: E/TelephonyManager(276): Hidden constructor called more than once per process!
09-17 13:01:55.266: E/TelephonyManager(276): Original: com.google.android.location, new: com.google.android.gsf
09-17 13:02:09.415: E/TelephonyManager(89): Hidden constructor called more than once per process!
09-17 13:02:09.415: E/TelephonyManager(89): Original: android, new: android
09-17 13:02:10.956: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-17 13:02:10.976: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-17 13:02:10.976: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-17 13:02:10.976: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-17 13:02:11.017: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-17 13:02:11.017: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
09-17 13:02:11.017: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
09-17 13:02:11.036: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
09-17 13:02:11.056: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

And my code for .java file is:-

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);        


         mapview=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.zoom);
        LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);
        View zoomView=mapview.getZoomControls();

        zoomLayout.addView(zoomView,
                 new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mapview.displayZoomControls(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    } }
```

I am using the emulater with Platform level:3.2 and ADI-13

Please help me.I am not able to understand how to overcome this log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first half of the log (till the errors) is shown when you run heavy `CPU calculations` on your `MainUI` thread.

(Im not sure if this is correct, but i saw those log entry when i did this ).

And the second half says that the system was `unable to load those files`.

Check if they are there and if you have `r/w permissions`.

If not, edit the settings in your `manifest` file.

Comment: I had done the readwirte permission.Does the execute is also be checked as mark??

Comment: im sorry i don't understand what you are asking. Maybe you can use StrictMode to find out where your cpu calculations are done on the MainUI thread http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I had solved the issue by creating again the AVD manager and build the project.